# Sealed vs sealed off

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

Let's say you can't open a strawberry jam's jar, and you are describing it this way:

> The strawberry jam is **sealed**.

Or

> The strawberry jam is **sealed** **off**.

Which of them is expressed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be more inclined to use:

> The strawberry jam is sealed **tight**.

(Grammatically, one might be inclined to use adverb *tightly*, but the word *tight* can be used in this context as well. See [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/adverb-usage-tight-tightly) for more on that.)

It might also be better to describe the *lid* rather than the *jam*:

> This lid is too tight.

I don't think *sealed off* is the right expression to use. When I hear that expression, I think of the police sealing off a crime scene, or a work crew sealing off an area with a dangerous leak. Cambridge defines [seal (something) off](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seal-sth-off) as:

> **seal off** (*phrasal verb*) to prevent people from entering an area or building, often because it is dangerous:
>   *Two more bombs have been discovered since the police sealed off the area*.

Comment: Thx. Can I say ''the strawberry jam's lid is *tightly sealed*'' or **sealed tightly** only?

Comment: Basically agree. Tight is not needed really. It can be used. But let's not forget to seal off for anything where there is a flow of liquid or other substance. They sealed off the pipes in the basement after the flood. seal off=stop a flow, even of people. Also, in every day language, we do say: the jam is sealed to mean the jar....

Comment: @Lambie - I concur on all the points you've made. Most of the suggestions in my answer weren't meant to be corrections, but thanks for clarifying.